# Combine template and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, iterator, containers

I have got an assignment to implement a few kinds of containers in a template fashion in c++.
All of this containers should provide an iterators with all sorts of operators overloading.
I am pretty new to templates, in fact this will be my first real project in this subject.

And this is my question:
Is using templates with inheritance a good idea in this case?
Could it be done for both the container and the iterator?
If so, what should i be aware of? 
What should i not do?
Any help on the subject will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither inheritance nor templates are goals, and neither is good
or bad in itself.  The question is: what problem are you trying
to solve?  The distinction according to the type contained in a
container should be made by the template: there's no good
solution for the return type if it is handled by inheritance.
How you manage the containment, advancing an iterator and
testing for the end *are* good candidates for inheritance, but
it still depends somewhat on the design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please elaborate on the problem i will face handling the return type when using inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

You're starting in a wrong direction. First create some alternatives you think could work (with and without inheritance), then compare them for pros&cons.

Or if you can't come up with one party, that closes your question fro good.

If you're new to templates I suggest start with   `typedef int VALTYPE;` and implement the container using that as regular class. Test it, and after you're finished you can replace the introduction so it will be template and VALTYPE a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start reinventing the wheel you should look at the containers in the standard and in boost ([Multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), [Pointer Container Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), [Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html), ...) and try to adapt one.

Answer (score -1):

You should start by writing the simpler container: a stack. It is simple because a stack does not need an interator.

I wrote you a small example of a stack implemented on top of std::list, with some inheritance.

Try to write your own first, but you can look at this one as a example if you want to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

/* Here mainly to demonstrate inheritance by providing a stack interface */
template<typename T>
class IStack
{
public:

  virtual void push(const T &i) = 0;
  virtual T& pop() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Stack : public IStack<T>
{
private:
  std::list<T>  _internal;

public:
  virtual void push(const T &i)
  {
    _internal.push_back(i);
  }
  virtual T& pop()
  {
    T& tmp = _internal.back();
    _internal.pop_back();
    return tmp;
  }
};
```

EDIT: Renamed based class as pointed out by James.

Comment: You should not ruin other people's homework. And if you do at least explain what useful purposes the base class serves balancing the complexity.

Comment: @BalogPal I explicitely stated that he should try to write his own first, this is just an example in case he want to see some code. Obviously the base class is here because he asked for inheritance and because, imo, using an interface when designing container can make sense. Also, what if someone else find this question because he looked to combine template and inheritance ?

Comment: Obviously, the base class here is _not_ a `Container`, but a `Stack`.  Depending on the naming conventions, it should be `Stack` (base class) and `ListBasedStack` (derived class).  But `Stack` is simple; the fun starts when you do have iterators.

Comment: Yeah sure, should've nammed IStack or something, I will edit. Indeed stack is simple, this is why I did go with that as an example.

Comment: The important thing to learn is not the syntax to have a base class, but to evaluate whether it is good bad or neutral.

Comment: @BalogPal In his case, probably. However if someone finds this question googling for "inheritance and template" they may want to see some code.